# Normal distribution has higher probability for multimodality than unimodality

Tags: r, mixed-models, gmm

I am trying to analyze a mixture model using the mixtool package, in other words, I would like to analyze if my data is a uni-, bi- or multimodal distribution.

For simplicity here an example:

```
library(mixtools)
#creating an aritifical normal distribution
mydata <- rnorm(1000, 1750, 60)

#defining the cuts and preparing it for calculations
cutp <- seq(1600, 2300, by=25)
mult <- makemultdata(mydata, cuts = cutp)
comp <- multmixmodel.sel(mult, comps = 1:3, epsilon = 0.01)

#plotting the data (in this case 2 subpopulations)
mixmdl = normalmixEM(mydata, k=2, maxit=50000)
plot(mixmdl,which=2)
lines(density(mydata), lty=2, lwd=2)
```

Now as a result for 'comp', I get:

```
          1         2          3 Winner
AIC    -Inf -94.04097 -124.04097      2
BIC    -Inf -35.04097  -35.04097      2
CAIC   -Inf -64.54097  -79.54097      2
ICL    -Inf -35.04097  -35.04097      2
Loglik -Inf -35.04097  -35.04097      2
```

In my very limited understanding for this kind of executions, I expected to see 1 as a 'winner' (since I produced a single normal distribution). 
However, as you can see, I get infinite values for 1, and identical values for the BIC, ICL and Loglik for 2 and 3. This speaks against a normal distribution and a higher (or identical) probability to deal with a bi- or multimodal distribution. Since I used a normal distribution to start with, I would expect to see a highest probability for 1 and at least some differences between 2 and 3. What confuses me the most are the identical values for 2 and 3 in some of the tests.

So my question is why my approach fails to recognize the distribution as a gaussian and rather classifies it as bi- / multimodal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not know a lot about the `mixtools` package. I did give a little try with the what you did, and I did not come to the same conclusion as you.

When I fit a two-component multinomial mixture model (which is what you are doing with `multmixmodel.sel`), the second component is non-existent; the posterior probability is almost zero.

```
set.seed(1)
mydata <- rnorm(1000, 1750, 60)

cutp <- seq(min(mydata), max(mydata), by=25)
mult <- makemultdata(mydata, cuts = cutp)

multmod2 <- multmixEM(mult, k=2)

multmod2 $posterior
# comp.1        comp.2
# [1,]      1 1.980052e-226
```

When I fit mixture models to the original data, the single component is selected each time.

```
library(mclust)
fit <- Mclust(mydata)
fit
#'Mclust' model object:
#  best model: univariate normal (X) with 1 components


library(EMMIX)
# Available from 
#https://people.smp.uq.edu.au/GeoffMcLachlan/mix_soft/EMMIX_R/

fit_1 <- EMMIX(mydata, g=1)
fit_2 <- EMMIX(mydata, g=2)

c(fit_1$bic, fit_2$bic)
# [1] 11108.02 11128.67
#(BIC selects the one component model)
```

Comment: Thank you. When I reproduce your approach, I get the exact same results. However, the mixmodel.sel still gives me the above values... I will try solve my problem using mclust.

Comment: No worries. I haven't used `mixtools` much. So, it is difficult for me to tell you why this happens with the `mixmodel.sel`.